# Samsung Galaxy s3 won't boot

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, boot

My Samsung keep booting up and then after the intro where it should show my home screen it showing a blue flashing Samsung sign with the Led light glowing blue as well. I have tried taking out the battery and holding down volume+home+power button. and holding the home button for restarting it. it's frustrating me

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts, Erica -- and thanks for sharing your concern! However, we are a Q&A site. To answer your question we need to know it. Could you please update your post to let us know what exactly your *question* is? Do you get to the homescreen -- or is your device stuck at the "blue flashing Samsung sign"?

Answer (score 1):

Press and hold VOLUME UP and Home(center) button
Press Power until the phone vibrate
Wait until you see the Android logo then release all the buttons.
Select Wipe data/Factory reset with VOLUME DOWN, press Power (right hand-side)
Select YES -- delete all user data with VOLUME DOWN and then press Power
After format, press Power again to reboot phone. (select reboot system now)

Answer (score 0):

Try wiping it from recovery.

WARNING, it removes all data from phone.